# Multiplying two columnvectors in octave

Tags: octave

I have two column vectors in octave:

```
a=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]

b=[7;6;5;4;3;2;1]
```

I would like to multiply these two vectors:

a*b and a*b' both give the error:

```
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 7x1, op2 is 7x1)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try restarting octave, `a*b'` should work. What version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a*b` doesn't work because you can't multiply a 7x1 vector by a 7x1 vector. As has been mentioned in the comments, `a*b'` works (because now you are multiplying a 7x1 vector by 1x7 vector, resulting in a 7x7 matrix), and so does `a.*b` (element-wise multiplication). Here's what I get with Octave 3.6.2:

```
>> a*b
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 7x1, op2 is 7x1)
>> a*b'
ans =

    7    6    5    4    3    2    1
   14   12   10    8    6    4    2
   21   18   15   12    9    6    3
   28   24   20   16   12    8    4
   35   30   25   20   15   10    5
   42   36   30   24   18   12    6
   49   42   35   28   21   14    7

>> a.*b
ans =

    7
   12
   15
   16
   15
   12
    7
```